# iPhone - design of labels and text fields like iPhone address book

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create an iPhone application and I have normal text labels on the left and UITextField on the right side. This design looks not very nice...
But now I see the design of label - text fields inside the address book of the iPhone.

Here is a screenshot to see what I mean:
http://files.zimbra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/screenshot-2008-06-10-022326-0700-1.png

What need to be done to create such labels and text fields?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard way of getting that cell by initializing the table cell the following way:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Left Text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text  = @"Text on the right";
    return cell;
```

What makes the difference is the "Style". UITableViewCellStyleValue2 will make a two column cell like the one you show.

There are a few more styles, and they are great especially on early stages of development before you really polish the cell layout.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, but I need on the right side, the possibility to make modifications, so I will need a UITextField. If you click on edit in the contact of the address book, you have the same design, but it is editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom cell in IB with a design you like.

EDIT:
This is a good place to start: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

See the part on how to create custom cells in IB.

Comment: Hm, is it not a standardized element?

Comment: nope, I create similar custom cells in my SafeWallet password manager application. Look at the UITableViewCell.h. You have only 4 types of standard cells, which SDK provides. Anything else - you have a freedom to customize :)

Comment: Okay, but where can I get the source?

Comment: @Tim, this is a good place to start: [How to create custom cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Answer (score 1):

Play with font size, color, and alignment of your UILabels. That's all there is to it.

If you're wondering about the nice rounded frames around text fields, that's because the screen in question has a UITableView in the middle. That's where the rounded cells are coming from.

Comment: So I have to take a UITableView with customized table view cells?

Comment: You don't *have to*; that's what the Apple address book app does. You decide.